# Current order state in admin module

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to display the current order state for an order - which is a OneToOne relation on my entity.
I have tried all sorts of variations like:

```
First attempt:
this.repository = this.repositoryFactory.create('fe_pa_conversion');
const criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.addAssociation('order');

criteria.addFilter(Criteria.equals('stateMachine.technicalName', 'order.state'));

Second attempt:
const criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.addAssociation('order').addAssociation('stateMachineState');
```

All gives me an error saying association not found.
How do I load the current state for an order?

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain `addAssociation` for multilevel association. Instead you provide them as a composed string:

```js
criteria.addAssociation('order.stateMachineState');
```

Also this isn't necessary:

```js
criteria.addFilter(Criteria.equals('stateMachine.technicalName', 'order.state'));
```

I assume you want to create a comparison of two database fields. This isn't possible at at moment. The second argument of the `equals` filter is interpreted as a literal string. `state` also doesn't exist in the definition of `order`. If you just want to get the technical name of the current state, just add the association as described above.